# ActiveRecord validate url if it is present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I would like to ensure that my class's `url` property has a value and if it does, it is valid:

```
class Entity < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :url, presence: true, :format => {:with => URI.regexp}

end
```

In the rails console:

```
> e = Entity.new(name: 'foo')
=> #<Entity id: nil, name: "foo", url: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

Which results in two errors for the `url` attribute:

```
> e.valid?
=> false

> e.errors
=> #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007fed9e324e28 @base=#<Entity id: nil, name: "foo", url: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, @messages={:url=>["can't be blank", "is invalid"]}>
```

Ideally, a `nil` `url` would produce a single error (i.e. `can't be blank`).

As such, I've change the `validates` rule:

```
validates :url, presence: true, :with => Proc.new { URI.regexp if :url? }
```

I can't get the syntax to work, however.  What am I missing?

Comment: Does it works when you give `present?` like this `validates :url, presence: true, :with => Proc.new { URI.regexp if :url.present? }`?

Comment: I get a `is not a symbol` error using that syntax.

Comment: May be you can split it into two `validates :url, presence: true` and `validates_format_of :url, with:=> URI.regexp, if: "url.present?"`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Separate your two validators.

```
validates :url, presence: true
validates :url, format: { with: URI.regexp }, if: Proc.new { |a| a.url.present? }
```

***(almost) 2 year anniversary edit***

As vrybas and Barry state, the Proc is unnecessary. You can write your validators like this:

```
validates :url, presence: true
validates :url, format: { with: URI.regexp }, if: 'url.present?'
```

Comment: Is there a way to add the error that results from an invalid URL to the objects `errors[]` array?  Currently, `entity.url = 'foo bar'` raises an error (`URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?): foo foo`, rather than adding it to the collection.

Comment: Without using `Proc`:    `validates :url, format: { with: URI.regexp }, if: 'url.present?'`

Comment: `URI.regexp` is not a good validation of URLs. Consider that test cases like `a://` and `extra text http://google.com extra text` pass this validation.

Comment: Also without a proc: `if: :url`

Answer (score 5):

Separate the validators as in Yanis's answer, but you don't need a Proc for this.

You can use the [common validation options](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#common-validation-options) to bypass the `format` validation if the value is `nil` by setting the `allow_nil` parameter.

Alternatively, setting the `allow_blank` parameter would also work if the value is the empty string `''`, which may be more useful if you're setting `url` from an form input.

The complete validator could look like this:

```
validates :url, presence: true
validates :url, format: { with: URI.regexp }, allow_blank: true
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you really only need a single validation:

```rb
validates :url, format: { with: URI.regexp }
```

this will cover both the `url` being present and it being a url.

You might want to improve the error message with something like:

```rb
validates :url, format: { with: URI.regexp, message: 'must be a url' }
```

If you feel like you need separate error messages for blank vs invalid values then you can follow Barry's suggestion:

```rb
validates :url, presence: true
validates :url, format: { with: URI.regexp }, allow_blank: true
```